# NSDictionary in UITableView - using index path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am trying to populate my UITable view with data from a NSDictionary. It would be sweet if I were able to access the data using an indexPath like the one giving in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
{
"December 2012" =     (
    "2012-12-08 13:56:53 +0000"
);
"July 2013" =     (
    "2013-07-17 12:54:22 +0000"
);
"June 2013" =     (
    "2013-06-17 12:29:57 +0000",
    "2013-06-20 12:02:17 +0000",
    "2013-06-21 11:55:58 +0000",
    "2013-06-21 12:16:59 +0000",
    "2013-06-25 12:59:39 +0000",
    "2013-06-25 13:01:10 +0000",
    "2013-06-25 13:02:22 +0000",
    "2013-06-26 12:24:28 +0000",
    "2013-06-27 12:29:00 +0000"
);
"May 2013" =     (
    "2013-05-23 12:54:35 +0000"
);
```

}

```
2013-06-28 08:49:49.948 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x747b840> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.950 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x8563750> 2 indexes [1, 0]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.951 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x747e740> 2 indexes [2, 0]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.95  [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x7473880> 2 indexes [2, 1]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.953 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x747a5d0> 2 indexes [2, 2]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.954 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x7489550> 2 indexes [2, 3]
2013-06-28 08:49:49.955 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x818ddc0> 2 indexes [2, 4]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.298 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x955f6c0> 2 indexes [2, 5]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.330 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x8360750> 2 indexes [2, 6]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.346 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x85739e0> 2 indexes [2, 7]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.363 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x9560690> 2 indexes [2, 8]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.380 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x9065b00> 2 indexes [3, 0]
2013-06-28 08:50:10.998 [4714:c07] <NSIndexPath 0x9660f70> 2 indexes [2, 2]
```

Above you will see the layout of my dictionary and below it the corresponding index paths. What is my best way to get the the data out? Should I be using something other than an NSDictionary?

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode. (If you used `emacs` and `make` instead, that wouldn't make a difference.)

Comment: How you want your table view to look like ? with headers like 'December 2012' or with out then just table rows ?

Comment: Basically I just need the table rows. I already am using the headers in the section headers - so I just need to get the corresponding data rows for each section header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @wain and @pgd said . Take an Mutable Array then add each array,which you get from dictionary to that.

Eg:

```
  displayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // 

  NSArray *keys = [MyDict allKeys];  // Getting all key from you dictionary

  for (id key in MyDict) {
    NSArray *anArray = [dict objectForKey:key];

    [displayArray addObject:anArray]
}
```

While displaying use section number to get the array.

```
   NSArray * array = [displayArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Get the keys from the dictionary (`allKeys`), sort them and store them. Whenever the dictionary changes, update your sorted array of keys. When you get an index path, use it to get the appropriate key, then you have access to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

An `NSArray` of `NSArray`s would be more suitable to access with an `NSIndexPath`. Other than that, the solution by @Wait should work as well.